# Iterating over multiple model/data pairs in AMPL

Tags: ampl

Is there a good way to iterate over model/dataset pairs in AMPL in a `.run` file?

Say you have two different models for the same optimization problems, and four datasets. What I would do up to now was to make a `.run` file for each model/dataset pair, and run each individually, or keep one script for each model and manually solve for each dataset by modifying the `data (file);` command. But this is obviously tedious and inviable for larger projects.

So is there any good way to do this? What I've tried is something like the following (just a skeleton for clarity):

```
# Some global options


for {model_ in {'1.mod', '2.mod'}} {
    reset;
    model (model_);

    for {dat in {'1.dat', '2.dat', '3.dat', '4.dat'}} {
        update data;
        data (dat);
        solve;

        # Do some post-processing
    }
}
```

But `AMPL` whines about using the for loop's dummy variable in the `model` and `data` command. I've tried declaring `symbolic` parameters to store the name of the model and data file, but no good either.

Of course this would only be sensible if the models were similar enough, insofar as they could be post-processed in the same way. But there should *at least* be a way to iterate through the data files within one model without having to go like

```
update data;
data 1.dat;
solve;

update data;
data 2.dat;
solve;

update data;
data 3.dat;
solve;

[...]

update data;
data 427598.dat;
solve;
```

right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code has a `reset` inside a loop. This will reset the loop parameter, which is going to cause problems. For instance, if you run this:

```
for {modelname in {"itertest1.mod","itertest2.mod"}}{
    display (modelname);
    for {dataname in {"itertest_a.dat","itertest_b.dat"}}{
        display (dataname);
    }
}
```

it will print out the file names as we might hope:

```
modelname = itertest1.mod
dataname = itertest_a.dat
dataname = itertest_b.dat
modelname = itertest2.mod
dataname = itertest_a.dat
dataname = itertest_b.dat
```

But if we add a reset statement:

```
for {modelname in {"itertest1.mod","itertest2.mod"}}{
    reset; ### this is the only line I changed ###
    display (modelname);
    for {dataname in {"itertest_a.dat","itertest_b.dat"}}{
        display (dataname);
    }
}
```

then we get an error: `modelname is not defined` (because we just reset it).

However, even without that issue, we'll still get a complaint about using the loop variable.

### **Solution 1: commands**

Depending on exactly what you ran, you may have seen an error message advising use of the `commands` statement, like so:

```
reset;
for {scriptname in {"script1.run", "script2.run"}}{
    commands (scriptname);
}
```

This will then run whatever commands are in the listed .run files, and you should be able to nest that to call separate scripts to define the models and the data. Since you can't use a blanket reset without killing your loop parameter, you will need to use other options for updating the model files. AMPL offers the option to define multiple "problems" and switch between them, which may or may not be helpful here; I haven't explored it.

The `commands` statement is documented [here](https://ampl.com/BOOK/CHAPTERS/16-script.pdf), although TBH I find the documentation a bit difficult to follow.

### **Solution 2: code generation**

If all else fails, you can write an iterated AMPL script that generates (and optionally runs) a second script containing all the model/data combinations you want to run, like so:

```
param outfile symbolic := "runme_temp.run";

for{i in 1..3}{
    for{j in 1..4}{
        printf "\nreset;" > (outfile);
        printf "\nmodel model%s;",i > (outfile);
        printf "\ndata data%s;",j > (outfile);
        printf "\nsolve;" > (outfile);
        # add post-processing here as desired
    }
}
close (outfile);
include runme_temp.run;
```

This will create and then call "runme_temp.run" which looks like this:

```
reset;
model model1;
data data1;
solve;
reset;
model model1;
data data2;
solve;
```

etc. etc. Since this *does* allow you to use a blanket `reset;` it might simplify the process of cleaning up previous models. Not the most dignified solution, but it works and can be adapted to a wide range of things.

This could be improved by de-nesting the loops:

```
param outfile symbolic := "runme_temp.run";

for{i in 1..3, j in 1..4}{
    printf "\nreset;" > (outfile);
    printf "\nmodel model%s;",i > (outfile);
    printf "\ndata data%s;",j > (outfile);
    printf "\nsolve;" > (outfile);
    # add post-processing here as desired
}
close (outfile);
include runme_temp.run;
```

In this particular example it doesn't make much difference, but multiply-nested loops can run slow in AMPL; using a single multi-index `for` can make a big difference to performance, so it might be better to get into that habit.

Comment: I share your opinion on the ampl-book being a bit of a mess! In reference to your first solution, would we have to separate the model commands and data commands in different scripts? I.e., would the "main" script call `script1.run`, and then `script1.run` would refer to `interest1.mod` as the model and both `interest_a.dat` and `interest_b.dat` as data files? Or would `script1.run` just select the model and then the "main" script select each of `interest_a.dat` and `interest_b.dat` before incrementing to the next model? Sorry if I'm not being too clear...

Comment: Depends how you want to loop it. If you want to test on a Cartesian product of models and data, then you'd probably want something structured with nested loops like your original code, but using one lot of commands to call scripts for the models and another to call scripts for the data. OTOH, if you only wanted to test specific model/data combinations, I guess each model/data combination would be one script, more like the example I posted.

Comment: Actually, rather than nested loops, use a single `for` with multiple index variables if possible - see my recent edit.